# Is 'the most remarkable thing that can be readjusted by environmental cues is our body clocks' grammatical?

Tags: agreement

> The most remarkable thing that can be readjusted by environmental cues is our body clocks

I think the subject and the compliment do not match and look awkward. What do you think?

Comment: It's perfectly fine. But you may want to use a singular 'clock' anyhow for other reasons.

Comment: Can you tell me what other reasons there are?

Answer (score 4):

The subject "thing" is singular, and so "is" is correct. It is grammatical.

The number of the predicate is not relevant.

For example:

> Our team is 20 players.

(in American English)

> The problem is Tom, Dick, and Harry.